# ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity source not found

Tags: android, dictionary, google-api

sorry i don't understand why my app crashes, i've created an activity with a mapfragment and a button, so it's very simple, but when i start app, it crashes and logcat sends me this error:

```
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frank.nuova/com.frank.nuova.Online}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at com.frank.nuova.Online.onCreate(Online.java:51)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         ... 11 more
```

manifest is ok i've already put all permissions and API key...i'm trying also to debug app and give me at first step

> ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity source not found

and second step

```
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 799 source not found
```

i don't understand why give me this error and also what is this errors?

this my code

```
package com.frank.nuova;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Online extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    Gps s;
    DataSource db;
    MyOpenHelper o;
    LatLng adesso;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            o=new MyOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
            db=new DataSource(o);
            try{
                o.createDataBase();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                o.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double lon;
            double lat;
            s=new Gps(getApplicationContext());
            s.getLocation();
            lon=s.longitudine();
            lat=s.latitudine();
            adesso=new LatLng(lat, lon);
            map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa)).getMap(); 
            Marker posizione=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(adesso).title("Sei Qui"));
            Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    List<Coordinate> b=db.vicino_online(adesso, db.vediCoordinate());
                    Marker[]a=new Marker[b.size()];
                    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                        String linea=b.get(i).getLinea()+"-"+b.get(i).getVia();
                        a[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(b.get(i).getLatitudine(), b.get(i).getLongitudine())).title(linea));

                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }
}
```

i also try to put `if(map==null)` before instatiate GoogleMap but i've same errors...

---

code :

```
package com.frank.nuova;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Online extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    Gps s;
    DataSource db;
    MyOpenHelper o;
    LatLng adesso;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            o=new MyOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
            db=new DataSource(o);
            try{
                o.createDataBase();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                o.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double lon;
            double lat;
            s=new Gps(getApplicationContext());
            s.getLocation();
            lon=s.longitudine();
            lat=s.latitudine();
            adesso=new LatLng(lat, lon);
            map=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa)).getMap();
            Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    List<Coordinate> b=db.vicino_online(adesso, db.vediCoordinate());
                    Marker[]a=new Marker[b.size()];
                    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                        String linea=b.get(i).getLinea()+"-"+b.get(i).getVia();
                        a[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(b.get(i).getLatitudine(), b.get(i).getLongitudine())).title(linea));

                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frank.nuova/com.frank.nuova.Online}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at com.frank.nuova.Online.onCreate(Online.java:49)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-30 11:02:16.289: E/AndroidRuntime(23018):    ... 11 more
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prima"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mappa"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/premi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: read your stacktrace again. the actual error (that is, the one with your coding involved) is `java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 15:32:18.678: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):         at com.frank.nuova.Online.onCreate(Online.java:51)`

Comment: so error is to instatiate GoogleMap but why? in another app this works

Comment: can you post your *actual* code? what you posted cannot have caused this exact stacktrace (line 51 cannot cause a NPE).

Comment: you'll have to post the layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have `NullPointerException` at `b.setOnClickListener`,
make sure you have  `Button` with `button1` id in `activity_main` layout

Comment: sorry line 51 is map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa‌​)).getMap();

Comment: Sure? re write the line to Fragment fg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa‌​‌​)); and check fragment is NULL?. and make sure you have 'mappa‌​‌​' at 'activity_main' layout

Comment: do you have other Layout xml with 'button1' id or 'mappa‌​‌​' id ?

Comment: yeah i've another layout with button1...i try to change id
EDIT: i've same error...

Comment: change it(not the 'activity_main' layout) clean the project AND run

Comment: nothing same errors...error is on map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa‌​‌​)).getMap();

Comment: have you tried this 'Fragment fg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa‌​‌​));' if(null!=fg)' ?

Comment: ok now it works but to get a map?, i don't put any marker on fragment?
and also doesn't open map on fragment...

Comment: try this way 'SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mappa);map = mapFrag.getMap();'

Comment: Sorry, the 'getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mappa‌​‌​‌​))' return null you should search why, i dont have any idea.

Comment: nothing now error is on map = mapFrag.getMap(); same error before :( i'm going crazy

Comment: check this example https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-, maybe we miss something, what SupportLib rev you use? if you use the latest try an older one.

Comment: i try code with another project and it works but if i use same code on my application it give me same error...maybe because this activity is called by another activity???